# Created a DOM element using jQuery is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a DOM element using jQuery:

```
var placeHolder = $("<li></li>",{text: "PlaceHolder",class:"placeHolder"});
```

This is working fine on chrome but getting compilation error on IE8.

Error "Expected identifier,string or number".

Comment: What version of jQuery? Try `$("<li/>",...)` and `"class"` in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Code**

```
var placeHolder = $("<li></li>", {text: "PlaceHolder", 'class':"placeHolder"});
$('body').append(placeHolder);
```

Comment: Thanks, your ans is correct. Please explain me my mistake.

Comment: I have just put the class into "class"

Comment: That I got. But what difference it made ? . Ok You mean class is a keyword that's why I got error. "class" means string. Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var placeHolder = $('<li class="placeHolder">PlaceHolder</li>');
```

or:

```
var placeHolder = $("<li />", {text: "PlaceHolder", "class":"placeHolder"});
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this syntax,

```
var placeHolder = $("<li></li>").addClass("placeHolder").text("PlaceHolder")
```

using addClass(), text() other jQuery methods is a preferable way for these purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
var placeHolder = $("<li/>", { "text": "PlaceHolder", "class": "placeHolder" });
```